# I want to open a link in my app window in Android

Tags: android, webview

Hello I am new to Android development. And I want to make an app that will open a link.For this I used web view but then also my link is being opened in browser not in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android WebView for this. Please follow the this link to know how to use android webview to load links [Example link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm)

Comment: thanks your answer helped me upto some extent but when I click on button to goto google.com then it opens my webview.XML file but again goes to my browser and displays the result. But I don't want the browser to open please help me out

Comment: Check you button click function. Remove calling browser intent related code. Code like ACTION_VIEW should be remove. Your button function should only contain webview.loadurl() method call only.